# Converting P-25Y-11M-16D to days

Tags: java, xslt

I have to find the difference between two years hiredate-current date but in mule esb data weave, I got the result as `P-25Y-11M-16D`. Is there any built-in function to convert from `P-25Y-11M-16D` format to number of days in java?

I have tried with delimiter and extracted the digits then multiplied and converted to days, but is there any short code for this?

Comment: Could you give an example of input / output? What is the exact rule?

Comment: this 'll never be an exact, but estimated result. How are you to know how many leapyears were there?

Comment: May be by dividing the years and adding those numbers to the final result

Comment: It's also a problem that you don't know how many days the month have? Does `P-25Y-11M-16D` mean that we go back 25 Years 11 Month and 16 Days from now?

Comment: @SatheeshKumar: again, it'll only be an estimate. How do you know whether the first, or the third year was a leap year? if you don't know how many leap years there are in the list, it's guessing

Comment: You need to solve this problem at its source, when you still have access to the two given dates. The difference between two dates, expressed in years, months and days is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the format supported by the Java 8 [`java.time.Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) class.
So you can pass it as a period. If you then want to find out how many days this is, you need to pick a reference date (for example, "now", or any other LocalDate), then you add the period to it, and then you check how many real days there are between these two dates.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

Period p = Period.parse("P-25Y-11M-16D");
LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate d2 = d.plus(p);
// The following gets the difference in days (or any other ChronoUnit)
System.out.println(d.until(d2, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

Which outputs the number of days of the period at the current date:

```
-9481
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Calendar` for that. First you extract the dates from the String, then you process them with a `Calendar`:

```
String[] times = "P-25Y-11M-16D".split("-");
int years = Integer.parseInt(times[1].substring(0, times[1].length() - 1));
int month = Integer.parseInt(times[2].substring(0, times[2].length() - 1));
int days = Integer.parseInt(times[3].substring(0, times[3].length() - 1));

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -years);
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -month);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -days);
```

**EDIT**:

In order to receive the difference between the date that was calculated above and the todays date you can do the following:

```
long diffTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - cal.getTimeInMillis();   // difference in milliseconds
diffTime = diffTime / 86400000;         // 86400000 represents the  conversion from milliseconds to days. (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

Comment: You get the date here. He wants the number of days.

Comment: @blahfunk you're right, i've edited my answer accordingly!

Comment: `.getTime().getTime()`?

Comment: @blahfunk Calendar's `getTime()` method returns a `Date` object. `getTime()` on a `Date` object returns the date in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any built-in function to convert from P-25Y-11M-16D format to
>   number of days in java?

There is no way to convert a duration expressed in years, months and days to number of days, when the starting date is unknown. In *any* language.

The correct way (and the **only** correct way) to handle this is at the source. Tell your XSLT stylesheet to retrieve:

```
<xsl:value-of select="days-from-duration(current-date() - xs:date(hiredate))"/>
```

instead of whatever it's doing now.

Comment: What's the output of that, when you try it? My guess is that it's either `-16D` or an error. Read 10.5.3 of the xpath-functions spec ("The result is obtained by casting $arg to an xs:dayTimeDuration") and 17.1.4 of the xpath-functions spec ("If ST is xs:duration, or a type derived from duration, but not xs:yearMonthDuration or a type derived from xs:yearMonthDuration, and TT is xs:dayTimeDuration, then TV is derived from SV by removing the year and month components from SV."). But also the minus sign has to go in front of the duration for xpath duration types.

Comment: "*My guess is that it's either -16D or an error.*" Why guess, when you can test it yourself (and see that your guess is wrong)? First, the result type of days-from-duration() is xs:integer. Next, the duration considered here will be `xs:dayTimeDuration`, not duration in the format presented in OP (which isn't part of XPath - and for a good reason, as exemplified here). And the result *can* be either positive or negative. -- See a demo here: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWw

Comment: Since the question was "Is there any built-in function to convert from P-25Y-11M-16D format to number of days in java?" I assumed your code was doing that - convert `P-25Y-11M-16D` to a number of days. Now I see it is calculating the difference itself. Perhaps a bit more explanation in your answer would have avoided that confusion.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I thought it was obvious from the comments on the questions made by others and myself. I have added a clarification anyway.